# How to solve deprecated "event.PreventDefault()"?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have until now with success used event.preventDefault() in the following situation where I click on a button and creates a dialogbox in Javascript:

This part creates a button in Javascript:

```
var vGetBtn = document.createElement("input");
vGetBtn.type = "image";
vGetBtn.id = "btnGet";
vGetBtn.src = "/someimage.png";
vGetBtn.onclick = function (event) {
    myMethod(BodyControlName, AVoucherNo);
}
```

And this part is the function which has been called from the button

```
function myMethod(ABodyControlName, AVoucherNo) {
    event.preventDefault();
    voucherNo = AVoucherNo;
    // Create a dialogbox in JavaScript
}
```

But now event is deprecated - so what can I do instead with Javascript?
Is there maybe something I can do in JQuery instead?

I have googlet a lot without finding the correct answer ...

Regards, Michael

**UPDATE**

This is what I have tried now - but the code does not reach the alert()... ? So maybe this is the real problem?
Now the error is the following: "Uncaught TypeError: AEvent.preventDefault is not a function"

```
vGetBtn.onclick = function (event) {
    myMethod(event, BodyControlName, AVoucherNo);
}
```

```
function myMethod(AEvent, ABodyControlName, AVoucherNo) {
    AEvent.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
}
```

Comment: You can pass `event` as an additional parameter to `myMethod()`

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for commenting - I have tried this now - but then my dialogbox does not show :-(

Comment: So you changed both the function call *and* the function? Well I don't see the code for the dialog box, so maybe that's a different problem.

Comment: @Pointy I have now discovered that I even can't get an alert ... so maybe this is a problem too... I have updated my question with a note about this

Comment: Where are you adding the button to the DOM? Are you getting errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you should pass the event object to the handler function:

```
var vGetBtn = document.createElement("input");
vGetBtn.type = "button";
vGetBtn.id = "btnGet";
vGetBtn.value = 'Click me';
vGetBtn.onclick = function (event) {
    myMethod(event, 'foo', 'bar');
}

document.body.appendChild(vGetBtn);

function myMethod(event, ABodyControlName, AVoucherNo) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    voucherNo = AVoucherNo;
    // Create a dialogbox in JavaScript
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/8yarqmx2/

This works fine, so there must be something in your code that causes the error?